# How to align three images on a row

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

There will be a certain amount of images in database which is **unknown** when this page is being redirected, which means I can't set the amount of *div* accordingly. What I am after is no matter how many images are there, I would like to display it in a manner of three images in a row, the fourth one will start from the left side of a new row. I try to use col-md-4 try to align three images on a row, but the fourth image is either on the center or right side of the next row ?

[image]

This is what I am after. Let's say there are 5 images in database, I would like it to be displayed like this

[image]

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    @foreach($images as $image)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="{{ $image->image }}" alt="{!! $image->title !!}" width="50%" height="auto" >
            <div class="btn btn-primary edit-image-btn">Edit</div>
            <div class="btn btn-danger delete-image-btn">Delete</div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Where do you want to place the forth image?

Comment: @ItayGal in the database there will be unknown amount of images, might be 5 or even 10. What i'm after is retrieving all these images then display them in 3 in a row

Comment: OK, but that's what you got now. What about the second row? Do you want to place the forth image on the left?

Comment: @ItayGal what i got now is shown in the image above. Yes i wan the fourth one to start on next row on left side then the fifth one will be on right side of the fourth one and so on....

Comment: Please share your full generated code with css. The default behavior of bootstrap is to place the next item on the left. You probably have some css that changes that

Comment: @ItayGal i din do any css changes to this

Comment: Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/jnd54teb/ it's your code and it works

Comment: @ItayGal but wat u are doing, is that u set the number of div ahead. What im trying to do now is when this page is being redirected, i wont be knowing how many images are there in database

Comment: The HTML and CSS doesn't take into account the number of images. Yes my example is static, but you can statically add images in the fiddle to check the behavior.

Comment: You have + sign in the picture please share the code with it.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The height of your first image is greater than the height of images two and three, this means that when the fourth image is added it is added on a new line, but where there is first available vertical space.

You can actually incorporate both of the solutions below simultaneously, `clearfix` is the most appropriate and versatile, but there are some design benefits from the alternative solution.

### `clearfix` Solution

Adding a `div` with `.clearfix` will force the grid system to create what visually appears to be a new row. **This is the best solution**, you can compare the index of the image and add a `clearfix` div every third image.

### Alternative Solution

You could place your images as backgrounds to a `div` (rather than using `img` tags) and force these divs to be a set `height` using CSS. this isn't solving your problem, it is just avoiding it.

If you set the `background-size: cover; background-position: center center;` then all images would cover the available space, although you would lose some of the image this is the best solution design wise (my preference).

If having all of the image displayed is important then use `background-size: contain;`.

```css
.col-xs-4 {
   padding:4px;
}
   
.image-div {
   height: 100px;
   background-size:cover;
   background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Ej0hUpn6wbrOTJtRExp8jvboBagaz+Or6E9zzWT+gHCQuuZQQVZUcbmhXQzSG17s" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h4>Current Problem</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 row">

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff"  width="100%" height="auto">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"  width="100%" height="auto">
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"  width="100%" height="auto">
            
        </div>

       <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="alternative"  width="100%" height="auto" >

        </div>

   </div>
</div>


<h4>`clearfix` Solution</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 row">

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff"  width="100%" height="auto">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"  width="100%" height="auto">
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"  width="100%" height="auto">
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

       <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="alternative"  width="100%" height="auto" >

        </div>

   </div>
</div>

<h4>Alternative Solution</h4>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 row">

 
       <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="image-div" style="background-image:url('https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff'); " >
</div>
        </div>
         
       <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="image-div" style="background-image:url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'); " >
</div>
        </div>
         
       <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="image-div" style="background-image:url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'); " >
</div>
        </div>
         
       <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="image-div" style="background-image:url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'); " >
</div>
        </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm using @foreach to display all the images in my database, clearfix would not work

Comment: You can count images inside your loop and add clearfix after 3 items each time

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate the `clearfix` solution, and an alternative using divs with the image set as the background.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code and updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dgmrsnb6/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row images-wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use row and col class names in the same div:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @foreach($images as $image)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{ $image->image }}" alt="{!! $image->title !!}" width="50%" height="auto" >
                <div class="btn btn-primary edit-image-btn">Edit</div>
                <div class="btn btn-danger delete-image-btn">Delete</div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    @foreach($images as $image)
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="{{ $image->image }}" alt="{!! $image->title !!}" width="100" height="auto" >
            <div class="btn btn-primary edit-image-btn">Edit</div>
            <div class="btn btn-danger delete-image-btn">Delete</div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```